# Php date difference with month wise days calculation

Tags: php

```
$a = strtotime('June 3, 2011'); 
$b = strtotime('June 3, 2012');
```

i want this date in every month format and date diff can be in remaining days of month. like 3 Jun 2011 to 30 Jun 2011 & then start again from 1 July 2011 to 31 July 2011 & finally 1 jun 2012 to 3 jun 2012 (with no of days diff in jun 2012). All are start with 1 to 30 or 31 of month (Month start and Month End date)format with days calculate in every month. So how we can do this..

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can gather what you want. It is better to show desired result

Comment: i want no. of days of every month in between dates of  'June 3, 2011' to 'June 3, 2012'

Comment: read about DateTime::diff - http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#example-2523